# Effective hamiltonians: how to deal with their explicit energy dependence?

Tags: condensed-matter, perturbation-theory, many-body

Suppose we are given a Hamiltonian $H = H_0 + V$ and $H_0$ has a degenerate ground state manifold (with a finite gap above it). If we denote the ground state subspace of $H_0$ as $\mathcal H$, we can decompose the total Hilbert space as $\mathcal H_\textrm{tot} = \mathcal H \oplus \mathcal H^\perp$. We are interested in the effective Hamiltonian of $H$ within $\mathcal H$. Standard methods prove that the following indeed has the correct spectrum:

$$H_\textrm{eff}(E) = E_0 + P V P + P V G_0'(E) V P + P V G_0'(E) V G_0'(E) V P + \cdots$$

where $P$ projects onto $\mathcal H$ (such that $E_0 = P H_0 P$), and $G_0(E)'$ is defined as follows:

$$ G_0(E)' = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 0 & \textrm{ in } \mathcal H \\ \frac{1}{E-H_0} & \textrm{ in } \mathcal H^\perp \end{array} \right. , \textrm{ or equivalently} = P^\perp \frac{1}{E-H_0} P^\perp \textrm{ with } P^\perp = 1-P.$$

The curious thing about the effective Hamiltonian is that it is energy dependent. One can argue that to lowest order we can take $H_\textrm{eff}(E) = H_\textrm{eff}(E_0)$.

**But what does one *in practice* do when computing the next-to-leading order contributions to the effective Hamiltonian, using the above method? I.e. how does one deal with the $E$-dependence?** (I gather that $E$ needs to satisfy the consistency relation that $H_\textrm{eff}(E)$ has an eigenvalue $E$, but I don't really see how one implements that in practice. Is one supposed to diagonalize the leading order effective Hamiltonian and use that spectrum in the next step?)

Comment: Can you give more details about how to get the effective Hamiltonian?